# How to read json data with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm getting this response when executing upload button from my page (I'm using jQuery File Upload).

```
readyState: 4
responseText: {"files":[{"name":"MY_PICTURE.JPG","size":79362,"type":"image\/jpeg","url":"https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/lib\/plugins\/jQuery-File-Upload-9.11.2\/server\/php\/files\/55_ads_1_preuzmi.jpg","mediumUrl":"https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/lib\/plugins\/jQuery-File-Upload-9.11.2\/server\/php\/files\/medium\/55_ads_1_preuzmi.jpg","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/lib\/plugins\/jQuery-File-Upload-9.11.2\/server\/php\/files\/thumbnail\/55_ads_1_preuzmi.jpg","deleteUrl":"https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/lib\/plugins\/jQuery-File-Upload-9.11.2\/server\/php\/index.php?file=55_ads_1_preuzmi.jpg","deleteType":"DELETE"}]}
responseJSON: [object Object]
status: 200
statusText: OK
```

I just want to grab name key value, nothing else I do not need. I'm stuck with reading name field value with title "name" (I want to grab this: MY_PICTURE.JPG).
How can I grab it with JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: `xhr.responseText.files[0].name` ? `xhr` being the supposed object containing the JavaScript data you posted. If my previous expression doesn't work, you may have to parse the JSON data with `JSON.parse` : `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).files[0].name`

Comment: Thanks! I've been starting to loosing my head about this! Problem was I stringified it first I see now.

Comment: 'Til this day I still get this problem, don't worry. Just remember that what seems to be a JSON object can also be a string sometimes. This happens especially when you transfer objects over a network (with AJAX, XHR etc.). Now you how the conversion works : `JSON.parse(json_string) // renders object` and `JSON.stringify(json_object) // renders string`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

With your example you can get the values like so :

```
for (var i in obj.files){
    console.log(obj.files[i]); // Here is the whole object
    console.log(obj.files[i].name); // Here is the name of the object
}
```

If you only have 1 entry, use the code that Blazemonger put in the comments of this answer :)

Comment: I know. Doesen't work, I can't get name. How must i spell it? Where I must put my response if using this example?

Comment: He used a simplified example. In your case, you'd need to fetch `obj.files[0].name`

Comment: Use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to check the structure of the JSON.

You have an array called "files", containing several arrays with names, sizes, etc. In order to access a property of one of these, you have to iterate through the array.

Edited my answer to show you how to parse your data.

Comment: after doing the 

    var obj = jQuery.parseJson(<jsonString>)

then, do a :

    console.log(obj)

and your entire object will get printed out to the console (you can expand/contract it and explore it) and then you can see what everything is really named and its real structure.

that should help.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you. The following will print all properties of the *file* objects.

**HTML markup to print json object values**

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

You can use [Object.Keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the properties of a javascript object.

**Script**

```js
var jsonString = '{"files":[{"name":"MY_PICTURE.JPG","size":79362,"type":"image\/jpeg","url":"https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/lib\/plugins\/jQuery-File-Upload-9.11.2\/server\/php\/files\/55_ads_1_preuzmi.jpg","mediumUrl":"https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/lib\/plugins\/jQuery-File-Upload-9.11.2\/server\/php\/files\/medium\/55_ads_1_preuzmi.jpg","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/lib\/plugins\/jQuery-File-Upload-9.11.2\/server\/php\/files\/thumbnail\/55_ads_1_preuzmi.jpg","deleteUrl":"https:\/\/www.mysite.com\/lib\/plugins\/jQuery-File-Upload-9.11.2\/server\/php\/index.php?file=55_ads_1_preuzmi.jpg","deleteType":"DELETE"}]}';

var myData = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $list = $('#list');
    $.each(myData.files, function(i,v) { // Iterate over the files collection
         var keys = Object.keys(v);
        $.each(keys, function(i,g){ // Iterate over the properties of each file object
               $('<li>' + '<b>' +  g + '</b>' +  " - "  + v[g] +  '</li>').appendTo($list);
              
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```